# Undefined variable when using Laravel Mail

Tags: php, email, laravel, undefined

no idea why this is happening.

Heres a basic code I am testing:

```
<?php

// get each user and send an email
$query = DB::table('users')->where('email', 'craiglovelock54@hotmail.co.uk')->get();

foreach ($query as $user) {
  $email = $user->email;
  $data = array();
  Mail::send('emails.wereback', $data, function($message)
  {
    $message->from('hello@buildsanctuary.com', 'BuildSanctuary');
    $message->to($email);
    $message->subject("We are back online!");
  });
}

?>
```

This is giving me an error of undefined variable '$email'.

The problem is, if I dont try to send an email and instead just echo out the $email variable it works perfectly fine...

Answer (score 3):

You have to import your `$email` variable into the closure's scope with the `use` keyword:

```
Mail::send('emails.wereback', $data, function($message) use ($email)
{
    $message->from('hello@buildsanctuary.com', 'BuildSanctuary');
    $message->to($email);
    $message->subject("We are back online!");
});
```